# Using ASP.NET Core Web API with ASP.NET MAUI - Can I use the models from API in my MAUI or do I have to recreate?

Tags: maui, .net-maui, core-api

Using ASP.NET Core Web API with ASP.NET MAUI - Can I use the models from API in my MAUI or do I have to recreate?

I just started working with MAUI and it seems like I have to re-create all my models in it.  For example I have a User model in API with username, name, email, etc.   do I have to create it again in MAUI?/

Comment: If they are plain C# classes, yes.  Place them in a separate library project so both other projects can reference them

Comment: ok thanks, might be a dumb question, but the models I have in my MAUI have extra line of code: PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(UserId)));  and this was based on what I've worked with, not sure what this does or why I have it.  Any idea?

Comment: Google “INotifyPropertyChanged”